# Button show div without deleting the previous div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So,I have 8 buttons. Each one shows a div when it's pressed.The problem is that when I press multiple buttons , all of them show their divs and don't delete the previous ones. What can I do?
Html:

```
<button id ="btn1" >a</button>
<button id ="btn2">b</button>
<button id ="btn3">c</button>
<button id ="btn4">d3</button>
<button id ="btn5">e 4</button>
<button id ="btn6">f 5</button>
<button id ="btn7">g 6</button>
<button id ="btn8">h 7</button>

<div id="story">asdaasdasdasdadsasdsds</div>
<div id = "z2">asdaasdadsd</div>
<div id = "z3">asdasdasdad</div>
<div id = "z4">asdasdasdad</div>
<div id = "z5">asdasdasdad</div>
<div id = "z6">asdadsdaad</div>
<div id = "z7">asdads</div>
```

CSS:

> #z1,
>    #z2,
>    #z3,
>    # z4,
>    #z5,
>     #z6,
>     #z7
>
> { display: none; }

JQuery:

```
$(function() {

$('#btn1').on('click', function() {

    $('#story').fadeToggle(400);
}); 

$('#btn2').on('click', function() {

    $('#z1').fadeToggle(700);
}); 

    $('#btn3').on('click', function() {

    $('#z2').fadeToggle(700);
});

    $('#btn4').on('click', function() {

    $('#z3').fadeToggle(700);
});

    $('#btn5').on('click', function() {

    $('#z4').fadeToggle(700);
});

    $('#btn6').on('click', function() {

    $('#z5').fadeToggle(700);
});

    $('#btn7').on('click', function() {

    $('#z6').fadeToggle(700);
});

    $('#btn8').on('click', function() {

    $('#z7').fadeToggle(700);
});

});
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "press on multiple of them" but it seems to be working for me for how it is coded. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edq5j/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class to your div "divToHide" for instance and call

```
 $('.divToHide').hide();
```

in your click method

here is a fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/U5PEu/1/

You by the way have an extra space into you css between # and z4

Answer (score 1):

You're not hiding the others because you're not doing anything with them. Try changing *all* of your on click handlers to be like this:

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    // hides currently shown divs
    $('.visible').removeClass('visible').fadeOut(700); 

    // shows div in question, and adds a class that can be queried later
    $('#story').addClass('visible').fadeIn(400);
});
```

The "visible" class that is added can be used to collect and remove any visible divs (or any element, really), regardless of what showed them.